# Which are the possible Software Architectures to use with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am confused as to which software architecture to use above ROS. I am building a Mobile Robot for Navigation. Frobomind is one possible Architecture to use. But are there any more alternatives. Can anybody please share their experience with me.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191250/which-are-the-possible-software-architectures-to-use-with-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're asking about [cognitive architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_architecture), or the broader class of [agent architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_architecture). Following any of the links from those pages will be just a start in discovering alternatives.

You should know Rodney Brooks and the 'subsumption' architecture, since that kicked off a lot of architecture research back in the 80s/90s (and I might as well mention [Shakey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakey_the_robot) to really provide some history). Read something about 3T, SOAR, and ACT-R. You might want to read  [Cognitive architectures: Research issues and challenges](http://www.isle.org/~langley/papers/cogarch.cogsys08.pdf), P. Langley, 2009.

You might instead read the [FroboMind paper](http://www.mdpi.com/2218-6581/3/2/207/pdf) (from their website), then follow up with any of the papers cited in the bibliography.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2016-10-21**:
Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look at the links.